# How a Rakhi band should be?

Tags: festivals

On Raksha Bandhan, men are tied with a band on their hands by their sister. These bands are coming in different types in market such as cartoon characters, some designs, with stones etc.

Is there any explanation in scriptures on how a Rakhi band should be?

Comment: Just my personal opinion, Rakhi's shape doesnt matter, what matter is the lagni(feelings) of a sister :).

Comment: @Kedarnath yeah true, but having a band with full of designed stones hurts the hand alot while sleeping :P

Comment: Rakhi is a raksha Sutra which abides (the human wearing it)to a vow for the one who gives the thread to the person wearing it. The only restriction on rakhi thread is that it should be unbroken (akhand) and must be of silk and if not available of silk cotton is preferred.

Comment: This answer provides scriptures references on how it raksha should be made https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20010/8735

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Perfect Definition:**

> Rakhi is a sacred thread.

According to Hindu scriptures Rakhi can be defined as a thread **made of cotton thread that can be tied on hand with pure wish**. It can be even a piece of your cloth!!

It is kind of **bracelet**. Sachi tied a bracelet on Indra's hand.

> Any design is accepted. Because the wish for good has only one design -> purity.

Sisters buy cartoon rakhis for brothers who are children. These brother will love cartoons , so they buy it. Reasons may vary for choosing a rakhi. Mostly colors are golden or red, but one may choose other colors.

Some brothers like Rudraksha Rakhis.

But the importance is sister's prayer for his brothers' well beings. These prayers have power. That only make Rakhi protects his brother.

[Click Here,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raksha_Bandhan) there are many incidents from Hindu scripture based on Rakshabandhan.

> Hindu scripture has defined a rakhi to be sacred thread only. Whenever the term Rakhi is used in texts, in most texts it is referred as cotton thread or bracelet.

### Meaning of the rakhi

The word Raksha means protection, whilst Bandhan is the verb to tie.

It is believed that when a woman ties a rakhi around the hand of a man it becomes obligatory for him to honour his religious duty and protect her.

Traditional stories state that rakhis are blessed with sacred verses and are encompassed by them.

Sometimes rakhis are consecrated in rice and grass before they are given, and they are traditionally tied by people familiar with the Vedas.

Following these customs the rakhi is believed to remove sin from one hand and provide safety to the other. The protection offered by a rakhi is believed to remain for a year.

Ref - [Rakshabandhan](http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/religions/hinduism/holydays/raksha.shtml)