# What is the origin of Raksha Bandhan?

Tags: identification-request, festivals

Raksha Bandhan is a festival that celebrates the love and duty between brothers and sisters celebrated on the full moon day of the Hindu calendar month of Shravana. But what is the origin/story behind this festival? (Please quote from the scriptures if possible.)

Comment: There are multiple stories, check this: https://www.hindutsav.com/raksha-bandhan/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Raksha Bandhan was originally not a brother sister festival. **It has its origins in a rite known as Vedopakarma (the beginning of Vedic Studies).**

[Chapter 124(pg 28)](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12976/5/Chapter3_1505-1584p.pdf) of **Narada Purana Vol 4** gives a description of this Vrata performed on Sravana Poornima. It involves tying a Raksha on one's wrist to ensure an auspicious beginning of Vedic studies.

> **26-28. On the full moon day in the month of Sravana is the holy rite of Vedopakarma' (i.e. inauguration of Vedic studies).**
>
> On this day the rite of Tarpana unto the Devas, sages and the Pitrs is
>   to be performed through the Mantras of the Yajurveda. (The followers
>   of the Yajurveda perform this rite of Upākarma on the day). The
>   followers of Rgveda (i.e. Bahvrcas) perform this on the Caturdasi day
>   and the followers of the Samaveda perform this in the month of
>   Bhādrapada (on the Caturthi day).
>
> The worship of the sages is performed in the manner laid down in one's
>   own Sakha (branch of the Vedas). **The Raksa (holy string) should be
>   tied round the hand in accordance with the injunctions.**
>
> **29.White Mustard seeds, unbroken raw rice-grains and black mustard are washed in water kept in a bell-metal vessel and then tied in a red
>   silk cloth with a saffron-smeared thread. The devotee then worships
>   Devas and prays to Wisnu and others. Delighted in mind, the devotee
>   should lay down to a Brahmana and get the thread tied round his wrist
>   by him.**
>
> 30-31. Thereafter, he gives Daksina to Brahmanas and begins the study
>   of the Vedas. After ritualistically dismissing the seven sages, he
>   should wear a new sacred thread made by himself and coloured with
>   saffron, etc. According to his capacity he should feed the prominent
>   Brahmanas and he himself should take only a single meal on that day.
>
> **32.O Brahmana, if this Vrata is performed, it makes atonement for all omissions and commissions in the Vedic study. If the Vedic rites are
>   forgotten or are performed in contravention of the injunctions, this
>   holy rite rectifies it.**

The [adhyaya 137](https://archive.org/stream/puran_bhavishya/Bhavishya#page/n409/mode/2up) **Uttara Parva of Bhavishya Purana** gives an account of how Indra grew powerful against Mahabali and defeated him due to a Raksha tied by Indrani Sachi.

This story says that the Raksha bestows health, prosperity and progeny to the one that wears it. Here it says that Raksha-bandhana is applicable for all varnas.

[image]

**Here is my translation of the Hindi text** (for those that don't know Hindi). This story is narrated to Yudhisthira by Sri Krishna.

> In olden times of Deva-Asura conflict Mahabali was defeated by
>   Devendra. An afflicted Mahabali inquired Shukracharya of the cause.
>
> Shukracharya said:
>
> Winning and losing is due to the wheel of time. **For now, for upto a
>   year you should be friendly towards Indra for Indrani Sachi tied the
>   Raksha-sutra to Indra due to which he is invincible.**
>
> After the period of one year has passed all will be good with you.
>
> Krishna to Yudhisthira: **O king, this is the amazing influence of the
>   Raksha-bandhana rite, that bestows victory, happiness, progeny, health
>   and prosperity.**
>
> Yudhistira said: Bhagvan, on which tithi and in what way should the
>   Rakshabandhan rite be performed, please tell me.
>
> Sri Krishna said: O king! **In the month of Sravana on the full moon day**
>   one should wake early and by bathing etc purify oneself and through
>   varied shruti and smriti offer water oblation and tarpana to the devas
>   and pitrs. Similarly one should do tarpana towards the sages.
>   Brahmanas should perform sraddha according to the injunctions of the
>   gods.
>
> Later in the aparaha-kala **one should make a Raksha using cotton or
>   silk cloth filling it with akshata, white mustard seeds, gold, black
>   mustard, durva grass, sandalwood and tie it into a bundle.** **This should
>   be kept on a copper plate and with due injunctions (as per scriptures)
>   consecrate the Raksha.**
>
> In the courtyard a square space should be plastered with cowdung and
>   pedestal should be established where the king should be seated by his
>   priest consecrated by mantras.
>
> Everyone should be cheerful and auspicious sounds should be made. The
>   foremost of the brahmanas and married women should perform arghya etc
>   and honour the king with an archana.
>
> **Then the purohita should take the consecrated Raksha and tie it to the
>   king's right hand chanting [this mantra](http://kalkimantraa.blogspot.in/2009/09/raksha-bandhan.html):**
>
> > येन बद्धो बली राजा दानवेन्द्रो महाबलाः। तेना त्वामभिध्नामि रक्षे मा चल
> >     मा चल ॥२०॥
> >
> > yena baddho baliraja danavendro mahabala, tena twaamabhi badhnaami
> >     rakshe naa chala naa chala
> >
> > **I secure on you the Raksha which was tied on Bali, the King of demons.
> >     Therefore O Raksha! Do not ever fail to protect this Follower, do not
> >     ever fail.**
>
> Afterward the king should worship and satisfy the brahmanas with
>   beautiful garments, food and dakshina.
>
> **This rite of Rakshabandhana is recommended to all varnas. The person
>   that performs rakshabandhana so described remains happy for a full
>   year and is blessed with ample progeny and wealth.**

Comment: Nice answer mate