# Mentioning of Rakhi in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, festivals, shloka

Consider the [following](https://www.raksha-bandhan.com/legends-of-rakhi.html) paragraph from raksha-bandhan.com

> Raksha Bandhan finds a mention in Mahabharata when Lord Krishna advised Yudhishthir to perform the ceremony to protect himself and the army from the dangers of the war. It is said that Kunti, the mother of the Pandavas tied rakhi to her grandson Abhimanyu and **Draupadi to Lord Krishna**.

My doubt is that where can I find sloka Draupadi tying Rakhi to Krishna?

Comment: If your question is about origin of the festival, then it's a duplicate. Krishna advising to Yudhishtira is already mentioned there. [What is the origin of Raksha Bandhan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20002/5212).

Comment: Well he clearly is asking about the Mahabharata Sloka where Drapadi ties it to Krishna, so its not a duplicate.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury... Dude show me where he's asked for the "origin of Raksha Bandhan". He's asked for the shloka where Draupadi ties it to Krishna. He's not asking when this festival started.

Comment: And the answer to your question doesn't even have any reference to Draupadi tying it to Krishna. Where do you see any duplication??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the origin of Raksha Bandhan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20002/what-is-the-origin-of-raksha-bandhan)