# Why Avani Avittam (Upakarma) festival is performed? What's its history?

Tags: brahmins

What's the history of [Avani Avittam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upakarma) (Upakarma)  festival? What does our scriptures say about it? This is not about Raksha Bandhan but its purely about a festival for male.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the origin of Raksha Bandhan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20002/what-is-the-origin-of-raksha-bandhan)

Comment: Though usually Avani Avittam and Raksha Bandhan fall on the same Purnima Day in the month of Shravan, the two festivals are not similar. Raksha Bandhan involves both the brother and sister. Avani Avittam is a purely male affair, where the men change their old yagyopavith. This day ritually everyone starts to learn the Vedas and it is termed 'Vedarambam'. There are no such ceremonies in the celebration of Raksha Bandhan - this question is not a duplicate to the referred question on Raksha Bandhan.

Comment: Raksha Bandhan was not a festival for brothers and sisters originally. See the original question. It was Shravana Pournami or Upakarma. The answer in the first line gives the reason why it was originally celebrated. It later changed culturally to  festival of brother and sisters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Explanation of the Vedic Ritual of Yajur Upakarma, also known in Tamil as “Avani Avittam” :

**[UPAKARMA](http://hinduonline.co/DigitalLibrary/SmallBooks/YajurupaakarmaSanEng.pdf) (AVANI AVITTAM): NATURE AND PURPOSE**

> Upakarma  (/upaakarma/)  means  beginning  or  “Arambham”,  i.e.  to 
>   begin  the  study  of  the  Veda  (Veda  Adhyayanam).  For  example, 
>   Yajur  Upakarma  means  to  begin  the  study  of  the  Yajur Veda.
>   Those belonging to the Yajur Veda observe the Upakarma in the month of
>   Sravana (August-September), on the day of the full moon (paurnami).
>   Why begin study of the Vedas on this particular day? This auspicious
>   day also happens to be the day when Lord Narayana took the  avatara 
>   as  Lord  Hayagriva.  Lord  Hayagriva  as  we  all  know  restored 
>   the  Vedas  to  Brahma  and also is the God of Knowledge.
>
> The next question is: why do this every year? In  the not too distant
>   a past, Veda Adhyayanam was  performed  only  during  the  period 
>   Avani  to  Tai  (from  mid-August  to  mid-January).  Therefore, one
>   is supposed to perform an “utsarjanam” in the month of Tai, i.e., a
>   giving up of the learning of Vedas from Tai to Avani. Just like a
>   Upakarma function there was a Utsarjana function  in  Tai.  The 
>   period  between  January  to   August  was  then  devoted  to 
>   learning  other  branches  of  our  shastras.  Thus  the  cycle  of 
>   Upakarma  and  Utsarjana  with  regard  to  Vedic  studies  was 
>   established.  However,  this  method  took 12 or more years to learn
>   just one veda.  Slowly this became impractical and Vedic studies
>   continued throughout the year.

More details about what all rituals are associated with Upakarma can be read there as well.