# Where does it say that rakshabandhan's rakhi should not be removed for atleast 21 days?

Tags: rituals, astrology, festivals

https://mpbreakingnews.in/religion/rakshabandhan-2023-what-to-do-with-rakhi-after-rakshabandhan-how-many-days-should-it-remain-on-wrist-what-astrology-say-mas/

This above news website writes that one should wait for 21 days or atleast until the Janmashtami tithi to take off the tied rakhi thread from the wrist otherwise great danger should befall. The article says it is found in jyotish shastra.

Can someone please provide any references as to how long keep the rakhi thread or in general any sacred thread like ritual kalavas on our wrists?

I have seen some people keep it on their wrists for like forever, while other people take the old one when replaced by a new one.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20010/647